# How to let javacc not to escape chars when generating source code?

Tags: json, escaping, javacc

I use javacc 5.0 to generate a json parser with the grammar file: https://github.com/inqwell/json/blob/master/src/main/javacc/com/inqwell/json/JSON.jj

But there are some errors in the generated java source code.

```
char escape = '\u005c\u005c';
```

and

```
switch(echar)
{
  case 'n':
    buf.append(System.getProperties().get("line.separator")); to++;
    break;

  case 'r':  buf.append('\u005cr'); to++; break;
  case 't':  buf.append('\u005ct'); to++; break;
  case 'b':  buf.append('\u005cb'); to++; break;
  case 'f':  buf.append('\u005cf'); to++; break;
  case '\u005c\u005c': buf.append('\u005c\u005c'); to++; break;
  case '"':  buf.append('"');  to++; break;
  case '\u005c'': buf.append('\u005c''); to++; break;
  case '\u005cr': to++; if (to < len && s.charAt(to) == '\u005cn') to++; break;
  case '\u005cn': to++; break;
}
```

And in the grammer file, they are:

```
char escape = '\\';
```

And

```
switch(echar)
{
  case 'n':
    buf.append(System.getProperties().get("line.separator")); to++;
    break;

  case 'r':  buf.append('\r'); to++; break;
  case 't':  buf.append('\t'); to++; break;
  case 'b':  buf.append('\b'); to++; break;
  case 'f':  buf.append('\f'); to++; break;
  case '\\': buf.append('\\'); to++; break;
  case '"':  buf.append('"');  to++; break;
  case '\'': buf.append('\''); to++; break;
  case '\r': to++; if (to < len && s.charAt(to) == '\n') to++; break;
  case '\n': to++; break;
}
```

These case chars should not be escaped, but how to do it?

---

**update**

The code can't be compiled in my IDEA, please see my screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You show us the symptom but don"t show the cause. Please post your JavaCC and Java code.

Comment: The javacc file is provided at the beginning of this question. The generated java code is very long, so I just pasted the error part. PS: it's an old unfixed issue of javacc, it's a pity that javacc has stopped(it has been 2 years since its last release).

Comment: We have to switch to ANTLR...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no error in the generated code. The literals  `'\\'` and `'\u005c\u005c'` mean the same thing in Java. The reason is that unicode escapes are processed first and other escape sequences are processed later. See section 3.2 of the JLS (3rd edition) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html

---

**Edit**: The following was added in response to Freewind's comment

```sh
theo-laptop:src theo$ javacc JSON.jj
Java Compiler Compiler Version 5.0 (Parser Generator)
(type "javacc" with no arguments for help)
Reading from file JSON.jj . . .
Note: UNICODE_INPUT option is specified. Please make sure you create the parser/lexer using a Reader with the correct character encoding.
File "TokenMgrError.java" is being rebuilt.
File "ParseException.java" is being rebuilt.
File "Token.java" is being rebuilt.
File "JavaCharStream.java" is being rebuilt.
Parser generated successfully.
theo-laptop:src theo$ fgrep \\u005c JSON.java
char escape = '\u005c\u005c';
  case 'r': buf.append('\u005cr'); to++; break;
  case 't': buf.append('\u005ct'); to++; break;
  case 'b': buf.append('\u005cb'); to++; break;
  case 'f': buf.append('\u005cf'); to++; break;
  case '\u005c\u005c': buf.append('\u005c\u005c'); to++; break;
  case '\u005c'': buf.append('\u005c''); to++; break;
  case '\u005cr': to++; if (to < len && s.charAt(to) == '\u005cn') to++; break;
  case '\u005cn': to++; break;
theo-laptop:src theo$ javac JSON.java
theo-laptop:src theo$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_07
```

Comment: But they make the generated code unable to be compiled, and I have no way to fix it except manually modify them.

Comment: I was able to compile the generated source with both eclipse's indigo compiler and Oracle's 1.7 compiler.  See edit above.

Comment: Please see my updated question. The source code can't be compiled in my IDEA(or command line `javac`). I don't know why.

Comment: It's fairly clear that the javac errors you are getting are not related to the character literals.

It seems that IDEA is not happy with the literals, but is IDEA doing the compiling, or does it delegate compilation to javac? If those red squigglies really indicate compilation errors, I can only tell you that the IDEA compiler is not following the Java JLS.  I know that isn't a lot of help. On the other hand, if they are only warnings, you can ignore them.

Comment: You are right, I just use eclipse to compile the code, and no error reports. It seems an IDEA issue